# How do you access a tspan inside a SVG text tag?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, tspan

I have imported an SVG using  and I'm trying to access the `<tspan>` innerText, because I need to change it, but when I add an `id="test"` to the tspan using `document.getElementById('test');` yields no results whatsoever...

How can I solve this problem?

I am aware that I can change the inner text by using `element.innerText`, but my result is null...

My SVG:

```
 <text transform="translate(42.88 166.17)" style="font-size: 12px;font-family: SegoeUI, Segoe UI">Test test<tspan x="135.69" y="0" style="letter-spacing: -0.0634765625em">T</tspan><tspan x="141.38" y="0">esting</tspan><tspan x="0" y="18">Just a test</tspan><tspan x="0" y="36">test</tspan><tspan id="test" x="0" y="72">Change me via JavaScript</tspan></text>
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
            <object id="sidebartoggle" data="/graphics/test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onclick="toggleSidebar();" style="top:50%;right:1%;position:fixed;display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;width:500px;transform: translateX(99%); z-index:9999999;" >
            </object>
            </div>
```

I'm running the JS in the browser console so far.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, I forgot to do that. Please see the edited question

Comment: @RobertLongson there is JS in my question, it's `document.getElementById('test');` as noted in the question. There's no need to put more code for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm running the JS in the browser console so far as noted in my newly edited question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239153/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-munchkin).

Comment: HTML document, but I run it in the browser console meaning it has already surely loaded

Comment: Yes but in a different document, the contentDocument of the object element.

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo.

```
document.getElementByID('test');
```

needs to be

```
document.getElementById('test');
```

then it should work fine.

Comment: When I paste this into a SVG element and then do `document.getElementById('test').innerText = "hi";`, it works completely fine.

Comment: Maybe my HTML is at fault then? I use `<object>`. Edited the question again to contain this information

Comment: Hm, I think the only way to get this working then is to directly add the SVG contents to your HTML. It should work like intended, but your HTML file might get a lot larger.

Comment: what are the differences between your code snippets? they are exactly equal each other.

Comment: Last "d" in getElementById should be lowercase, not uppercase.